jOOQ throws error cannot access java.util.concurrent.Flow with 3.19.10
As the title says, I am unable to build my maven module using jOOQ as a dependency (3.19.10) even after using java version 17 to build my code. The pom.xml file also specifies java 17 as the source and target. I have also verified the JAVA_HOME environment variable. I do not get this error with jOOQ 3.14 (which is obviously because it does not depend on java 17) but I don't understand why is my compilation failing.
Here is the first line of my maven build:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.11+9\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.11+9
pom.xml dependency:
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
        <version>3.19.10</version>
    </dependency>

Maven 3.9.6

Can you please post the complete configuration of your maven-compiler-plugin?

So apparently it was because the parent pom.xml was using a different java version (8) and my module was not overriding it correctly
